# Subrouter issues with negroni / gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla, negroni

So I am trying to setup my router to respond to `/users` and `/users/{userId}` so I tried this code:

```
usersRouter := router.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()
usersRouter.HandleFunc("", users.GetUsersRoute).Methods("GET")
usersRouter.HandleFunc("/{userId:[0-9]*}", users.GetUserRoute).Methods("GET")
```

The issue is that I get a 404 error when I go to `/users` (but is does respond to `/users/`)  If I do:

```
router.HandleFunc("/users", users.GetUsersRoute).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/users/{userId:[0-9]*}", users.GetUserRoute).Methods("GET")
```

It works like I want it to.

Is there any way to get the URLs to work like I want with Subrouters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You can make the routes semi-work by adding StrictSlash(true) to the router.

Given the following code

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"

        "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    )

    func main() {
        mainRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
        mainRouter.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Fprint(w, "test") })

        subRouter := mainRouter.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()
        subRouter.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Fprint(w, "/users") })
        subRouter.HandleFunc("/{id:[0-9]+}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Fprint(w, "/users/id") })
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mainRouter)
    }
```

a request to http://localhost:8080/users will return

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: /users/
< Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 19:52:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 42
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
<a href="/users/">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

a request to http://localhost:8080/users/ returns

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 07 Apr 2015 19:54:43 GMT
< Content-Length: 6
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

< /users
```

so if your client is a browser then perhaps this is acceptable.